# View pending tasks

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

When the `drawnow` function is called matlab does all of the pending tasks. Is there a way to find out exactly what tasks it does?

Thus far in my search I've come across `javaObjectEDT` which seems to be what runs these tasks, but I was wondering if I can see what they are. I'd like to find out why my `drawnow` command takes .2 seconds.